# Only list scratch orgs relevant to project

Tags: salesforcedx

I have 2 devhubs that I use for different projects, stored in different folders. However when I go `sfdx force:org:list` I see scratch orgs from both projects - super annoying!

Is there a way to separate those so I only see ones relevant to my project?

Comment: One thing that somewhat helps is listing orgs in verbose mode and then looking at devhub id - `sfdx force:org:list --verbose` it's a bit too verbose for my liking (devhub name would be more user friendly, instance Ids are too long)

Comment: Ok so I've hacked up my own alias for this: `alias dxl="sfdx force:org:list --verbose --json --skipconnectionstatus | jq -r '.result.scratchOrgs[] | [.defaultMarker, .alias, .username, .devHubUsername, .instanceUrl] | @tsv'"`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use two separate logins on your computer, because the files are stored in ~/.sfdx (Linux, Mac, etc) or %HOMEPATH%/.sfdx (Windows), so all projects would see all logins. There's no easy way to do this with just a single user or specify authorized logins per project. You can, of course, set a default user and dev hub user per Salesforce DX project folder, which is usually enough for trivial cases.

Comment: Hmm. Weird oversight. The org list doesn't event show relevant namespace. Right now we have to fiddle with aliases.

Comment: btw I vaguely remember seeing the same question or solution on twitter ages ago, but failing to google it.